# How to call an invocable process (process builder) from a flow (Screen Flow)

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder, screen-flow

**I need a process to update an sObject name**, I tried doing this only with a flow, but **the related objects did not update the name of this object.**
The Name of the sObject is '*Cost Center*'

The user (through a Screen Flow) should be able to pick a 'Cost Center' and write down the new name for the selected Cost Center.

I've changed the name from "Sunday Morning People" to "Sunday Morning Cats" with a flow but...

The original object changed its name successfuly:
[image: test]

But when you open a record where this name is represented this field does not change:
[image]

[image]

So I decided to do this with process builder, but I still need the screen.
**How can I call a process from a flow and then go back to the screen flow?**
I'm kinda stuck.

**Edit:** If this is possible with a flow only or with subflows its okay as well.

The sObject 'Cost Center' doesnt do much, there are around 30 instances of this. And what makes the name is unique for each one.
The related sObject Story, has a field called CostCenter__c,  its a Picklist (Multi-Select) which is a Global Value Set (this is a list of all the cost centers).

Comment: Since Salesforce will begin [retirement for Process Builders in 2023](https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2021/go-with-the-flow-whats-happening-with-workflow-rules-and-process-builder), you don't want to go that route.  Please [edit] your post to include important details like what the related object is and your steps in the Screen Flow that retrieve and update the related records.

Comment: Hello David, thanks for the answer. I will try to do this only with flows then. How can I retrieve correctly the related records of an object through flows? Do you have any link?

Comment: See Salesforce Trailhead, documentation, YouTube and other web resources for good tutorials on building flows like this.

Comment: But if your Story object is related to Cost Center, why do you need a Flow to set the name?  The lookup field in the story record should show the cost center name automatically.

Comment: I edited my question: Apparently this is not a lookup but a global value set that has all the Cost Centers. Sorry, I'm having a hard time trying to figure this out. Thanks again for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

They are where not related in first place. For some reason what I thought was a relationship was actually a Global Value Set, which displayied a list of the existing Cost Centers.

So in order to acomplish this it is needed to create a flow that allows the user to change the object name, and update that list value as well so it will be reflected in the *"related"* object.